# How to get the reference in a select statement?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm working with Oracle 12c types.

Let's say I have a type called `TY`.

I would like to do this query:

```
select ref(TY(p1,p2,...,pn)) from dual;
```

It works without the `ref(...)`.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? Are you talking about like pointers to objects? Oracle doesn't work like that.

Comment: @eaolson - actually it sort of does, just not the way the OP is trying to use it. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjint.htm#i458258)

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle documentation says this about REFs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjdes.htm#ADOBJ7438):

> A REF contains the following three logical components:
>
> - OID of the object referenced. A system-generated OID is 16 bytes long. The size of a primary-key based OID depends on the size of the
>     primary key column(s).
> - OID of the table or view containing the object referenced, which is 16 bytes long.
> - Rowid hint, which is 10 bytes long.

These are all **locational**  attributes. They uniquely identify an instance of an object in an object-relational table. Your query fails because you are attempting to reference a transient object.

The value of REFs is that they allow us to reference an existing object, so we can navigate object hierarchies, enforce constraints, etc. What you are trying to do doesn't fit this usage.